# Dynamic Navbar content in an otherwise static page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a navbar that changes its content depending on whether the user is signed in or not. I want to use getStaticProps to get the props for the rest of the page but this makes the navbar pre-rendered and if the user logs in it stays the same.

The navbar is implemented in the _app page as it is shared between all the pages.

Here is my code:

```
    function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, appProps }) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Header
        links={
          <HeaderLinks user={appProps.user} />
        }
      />
        <Component {...pageProps} {...appProps} />
      <MyFooter />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
  const { token } = parseCookies(ctx);
  let appProps = {};

  if (!token) {
    const isProtectedRoute =
      ctx.pathname === '/account' || ctx.pathname === '/create';
    if (isProtectedRoute) {
      redirectUser(ctx, '/login');
    }
  } else {
    try {
      const payload = { headers: { Authorization: token } };
      const url = `${baseUrl}/api/account`;
      const response = await axios.get(url, payload);
      const user = response.data;
      // if authenticated but not admin or root then redirect from the create page
      const isRoot = user.role === 'root';
      const isAdmin = user.role === 'admin';
      const isNotPermitted = !(isRoot || isAdmin) && ctx.pathname === '/create';
      if (isNotPermitted) {
        redirectUser(ctx, '/');
      }
      appProps.user = user;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting current user', error);
      // delete invalid tokens
      destroyCookie(ctx, 'token');
      // redirect to login
      redirectUser(ctx, '/login');
    }
  }
  return { appProps };
};

export default MyApp;
```

I am wondering if there is any way I can make the content of the page statically generated using getStaticProps but the navbar props be dynamic so when the use logs in only the nav bar changes?

Answer (score 0):

Import the navbar as a dynamic import with `ssr:false` this means the client will only import/execute it.

```
const NavBar = dynamic( () => import('../components/NavBar'), 
{ ssr: false } )
// ... Rest of your statically generated page
```

More here: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr